# Cultural evidence or origins that name order indicated importance or authority

Tags: textual-criticism, jewish-culture, name

In the situation with Priscilla and Aquila, name order is often an argument within the egalitarian/complementation debates.

Listing order has been used to point out significance or importance in a number of areas and commentaries of biblical text.  It seems to be an accepted norm and most sources refer to well known cultural and traditional standards of the practice.

I have not been able to find any basis for this.  I’m not disagreeing with it but I would like to find a source where this is clear rather than just referencing “that what everyone says”.  What are the origins of this teaching?

Comment: Priscilla is first on two occasions : Priscilla and Auqila. Auquila is first on two other occasions : Auqila and Priscilla. (Just thought that needed to be pointed out.)

Comment: @NigelJ actually it’s 4 Priscilla to 2 Aquila but who’s counting :). The question isn’t about Priscilla. I’m questioning the rationale behind The statement that placement order signifies importance.  It always comes up. But What I want to know is where does that come from and are there other examples.  There should be something out there for it to be such a common assumption

Comment: I wasn't counting the Acts 18:2 as its not a list. Have to confess that I missed 2 Timothy 4:19 in the concordance as it's 'Prisca' in the KJV.